# Java script doesn't work on an external sheet but it works on the main html file. Why is that and how do I fix it?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my first main html code

[Main HTML file picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dK1O8.png)

and here is my second of my external file

$(document).ready(function() {

```
    alert("hello");

});
```

I already tried putting the alert outside of the document ready function it still doesn't work.

I don't know why only the first one works please help. Also when I opened up my devtools and went to console it had a lot of but i can't put most of them because I don't have enough reputation to post more than one link. But here is one,
GET http://online-dnbard.rhcloud.com/tick/5620f410e59615263f000006 net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

ps. I am using brackets.

Comment: because you're trying to use jQuery, and you probably don't have jQuery loaded, or loaded at the right time - without seeing your code (I **refuse** to look at an image of code you could so easily copy/paste here) it's only a guess - as for your errors, look for one that relates to the javascript you're trying to run, not just a random one you've picked from the many errors you are getting

Answer (score 0):

Note That you load up your external js file before jquery:

```
<script src="Javascript.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

When you load up your file, you reffer to "$(document).ready", which isn't defined yet, so your browser throws an error.

Just change the order:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="Javascript.js"></script>
```

ps. [Using the console](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Your_Browser_to_Diagnose_JavaScript_Errors) in the future will save you a lot of time ;)